# producing a scatter plot from multi-level dataframe [pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a big data frame, on which I've done a df.groupby(["event_type", "day"].count() and gotten the following multi-indexed df:

[image: counts df]

My aim is to produce a scatter plot that shows the number of occurrences of an event per day, sorted by event_type. So a scatter plot where the x axis is "day" and the y axis would be "id" from the above table (which is a count). But I don't know how to go about making it.

background: event_type is only 3 types. day is like 2 years of dates. "id" is id of things I'm tracking, but in the above .groupby() data frame, its actually the count of ids. I'd ideally like to get 3 separate lines plotted (one per event_type) of the id counts versus  day of the year. Thanks!

Comment: You should get into the habit of pasting data & code formatted as `code`, so that those trying to help you can copy/paste it when trying to write an answer.

Comment: `id` is a discrete variable -- that's already aggregated -- and `day` is a time series/categorical variable, so a scatter plot of this data is going to basically look like a point plot (or a line plot with only nodes). Consider instead a line or bar plot. `matplotlib.pyplot` is the most popular plotting library for python -- see example code for a bar plot here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help:

```
a['date'] = pd.to_datetime(a['date'])
for name, group in a.groupby(['type','date']).count().groupby('type'):
    plt.plot(group.reset_index().set_index('date')['v1'], marker=o, linestyle='', label=name)
    plt.legend()
```

[image]

If you want normal plot instead of scatter, remove marker and linestyle arguments. 
My DF looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like df[df['type'].isin(['type_a','type_b'])] and assign it to new df, and create graphs from the new one